# Pytorch nonnegative device index with CPU?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to run PyTorch with a cpu. I instantiate the device with

```
device = torch.device( "cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu" , index = 0)
```

and the output of `print(device)` is `device: cpu:0`.

But when I try to send tensors to my device with `.to(device)`, I get the error

```
RuntimeError: Device index must not be negative
```

Is there another way to manually set the index of a device?

Comment: There's not enough information to debug the cause of the problem. The code you provided works fine both w/ and w/o a GPU.